# Error occurred when C++ calls EVP_PKEY_decrypt in the OpenSSL library

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

When I use the OpenSSL C++ library, I first generate a pair of public and private keys. Then I encrypt a piece of string with the private key and try to decrypt it with the public key. However, when I run the code and reach the EVP_PKEY_decrypt function, I am unable to decrypt the string. Can you please explain why this is happening?

```
std::string decryptWithPublicKey(const std::string& publicKey, const std::string& encryptedText) {
    BIO* publicKeyBio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)publicKey.c_str(), -1);
    EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(publicKeyBio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free_all(publicKeyBio);

    if (pkey == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Error reading public key" << std::endl;
        return "";
    }

    //size_t decryptedTextLen = EVP_PKEY_size(pkey);
    //size_t decryptedTextLen = encryptedText.size();
    size_t decryptedTextLen = 2048;
    //std::cout<<"decryptedTextLen:"<<decryptedTextLen<<"\n";
    std::string decryptedText(decryptedTextLen, '\0');

    EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL);
    if (ctx == NULL || EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx) <= 0 || EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error initializing decryption context" << std::endl;
        EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
        return "";
    }
    
    
    //std::cout<<"decryptedTextLen:"<<decryptedTextLen<<"\n";
    if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, (unsigned char*)decryptedText.data(), &decryptedTextLen, (const unsigned char*)encryptedText.c_str(), encryptedText.size()) <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error decrypting data2" << std::endl;
        EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
        return "";
    }

    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);

    decryptedText.resize(decryptedTextLen);
    return decryptedText;
}
```

Even with the correct public and private keys, EVP_PKEY_decrypt still returns 0. Is there a problem with my decryption function?

Comment: Why do you decrypt with the public key? The public key is used for encryption. The private key must be used for decryption. You may be confusing encryption/decryption with signing/verifying (for the latter, however, the code is inappropriate, s. [*EVP Signing and Verifying*](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying#Asymmetric_Key)).

Comment: Note that EVP_PKEY_decrypt expects a *private* key, not *public*.

Comment: Also, OpenSSL provides a C interface, not a C++ interface.  That's usually not something to be concerned about, but there are going to be corner cases where it can make a difference.

Comment: And your cramming of multiple function calls into one line with code such is `if (ctx == NULL || EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx) <= 0 || EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0)` is a really bad idea.  You already have serious bugs in your error handling because of that.  Nevermind if one of the calls does fail you can't tell which one, and you can't single-step through that code with a debugger and actually see what's going on.

Comment: However, the official document of openssl contains public key decryption: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_decrypt.html

Comment: I followed the official OpenSSL documentation, but when I call the EVP_PKEY_decrypt function, it returns 0, indicating decryption failure. I don't understand why

Comment: *Public-key* cryptography is a synonym for *asymmetric* cryptography, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). In this sense, the term *public key decryption* in the documentation of `EVP_PKEY_decrypt()` is only intended to denote asymmetric decryption and does **not** mean that the decryption should be carried out with the public key. This is also clear from the [example for `EVP_PKEY_decrypt()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_decrypt.html), which **requires** a private key, quote: *NB: ...and that key is an RSA private key.*